Overflow content into a different block, without JavaScript
What I want to do here may not be possible, but I wanted put it out there first to see if anyone else may have a clever idea that escapes me.
I want to mimic the layout of a government form. Essentially, what I want to have is a "continued" block, where text that overflows the main text area on the first page will spill over into the proper location on the second page.
I have the following example code, which does what I want. The only issue with it is that it relies on JavaScript, which I cannot do. This is a print layout, and JavaScript doesn't work in the engine we use to render the HTML.


document.getElementById("content2").scrollTop = 150;
#content1, #content2{
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 250px;
      height: 150px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 5px;
  }
  #content2::after{
      /* 
       * This is a spacer to ensure we can scroll to a value that has no content if the 
       * overflowed content does not fill box 2
       */
      content: " ";
      display: block;
      height: 150px;
  }
<h1>Split up content</h1>
  <h2>Here's the first box</h2>
  <div id="content1">
      <p>
          This is some really long content.
      </p>
      <p>
          My goal is for it to start in the first content block until the overflow is reached, 
          and then the overflowed content will automatically be displayed in the second box.
      </p>
      <p>
          This is intended for use in a print layout, so I cannot rely on JavaScript.
      </p>
  </div>
  <h2>And here's the second</h2>
  <div id="content2">
      <p>
          This is some really long content.
      </p>
      <p>
          My goal is for it to start in the first content block until the overflow is reached, 
          and then the overflowed content will automatically be displayed in the second box.
      </p>
      <p>
          This is intended for use in a print layout, so I cannot rely on JavaScript.
      </p>
  </div>



Is there a way to accomplish this same thing without JavaScript? The only other thought I have would be to try and split the content before inserting it into our HTML temple, but this seems unlikely to work well, as we can't really tell where the breakpoint would be without, well...actually laying out the text.

No, there isn't

If Javascript can't work in the engine you use to print, what else doesn't work?

Generally support is pretty good, all considered. It supports HTML5 and most CSS3 I've tried. It struggles with some of the particularly advanced features of CSS Grid (like subgrid), but that's all I've noticed missing (aside from JavaScript, obviously).

That's not the point I was trying to make. You're asking us for a bit of code for a platform which you tell us virtually nothing about. All we know is it doesn't support Javascript. When asking a question here, sharing as much information as possible is the idea. Are you using some PDF rendering engine? Which one? Perhaps there is an alternative method we can suggest if you share enough information. This kind of problem is often called an XY-problem. It happens a lot here.

Understood. I have been using WeasyPrint.

OK, I see. What you could try is to just make one big text block and just let WeasyPrint split it up over two pages. As it says on this page: "This is when we decide where to do line breaks and page breaks. If a break happens inside of a box, that box is split into two (or more) boxes in the layout result.". This clearly wouldn't look the same as in the form in your question, but it is close.

Adobe & MIcrosoft proposed CSS regions 13 years ago. Sadly. it was opposed by the other browser makers so it has never progressed beyond that early draft status.

I eventually came up with a solution using floats. It's a little awkward, but it actually does work. We can use psuedo-elements as invisible spacer floats, and then make the "interrupting" content as a float with 100% width.


*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    width: 250px;
}
h2{
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0;
}
#title1{
    border-bottom: none;
}
#title1::after{
    /* This psuedo-element provides the height of the first block */
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    width: 0;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
}
#title2{
    /* This appears below the psuedo-element, interrupting the content text */
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
#content{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
<h1>Split up content</h1>
  <h2 id="title1">Here's the first box</h2>
  <h2 id="title2">And here's the second</h2>
  <div id="content">
      <p>
          This is some really long content.
      </p>
      <p>
          My goal is for it to start in the first content block until the overflow is reached, 
          and then the overflowed content will automatically be displayed in the second box.
      </p>
      <p>
          This is intended for use in a print layout, so I cannot rely on JavaScript.
      </p>
  </div>



